# Is there a way to purchase +100 GB on Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I need +100 GB cloud storage. So far, Google Drive and Dropbox give me good options, but I want a third option. If I purchase the +100 GB, would I be able to access it from my multiple devices?

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu one Page](https://one.ubuntu.com/services/#storage_panel) tells you everithing.

You can buy in 20GB steps. 100GB is no problem.

And yes. You can access with multiple devices and different os's.